# How to use insert in lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, random, count, insert

Ok im trying to create a program which generates a 10 character random password but the created password only has one character instead of ten

```
count = 0
while count < 10:
    new = []
    new.insert(count,(random.choice([random.choice(string.ascii_letters),random.choice(string.digits)])))
    count = count+1
print(''.join(new))
```

Comment: You're creating ten lists, each with one item. Also why not ,`for count in range10):`.

Comment: ohhh ya stupid me thanks haha